# how to advance one whole virtual window in follow-mode?

Tags: follow-mode

Is there a command for Emacs's `follow-mode` that will advance the text by a whole 'virtual window' rather than just the height of a column?

Desired effect:

Upon reaching the end of column 4, press `PgDn` (aka `next`), continue reading the next lines at the start of column one.

Compare with and without `follow-mode`:

When not in `follow-mode` I would use `PgDn`, but in `follow-mode` this only advances the text by the height of one column rather than the full height of the  'virtual window'

Is there a command other than `PgDn` that will manage this in `follow-mode`?

> Follow mode is a minor mode that makes two windows, both showing the same buffer, scroll as a single tall virtual window.

#### update

individually pressing `PgDn` four times

OR

individually pressing `C-v` four times

does scroll the column of text 4 times and so the whole virtual window (assuming there are 4 columns in follow-mode).

manually counting the lines tells me that
the text has been scrolled forward by 57 lines.

`C-u 57 C-v`
scrolls the same number of lines

#### still seeking

a single command that will, regardless of column height or number of columns, scroll a full 'virtual window'.

Comment: Do several `PgDn` work? As in, if you have 4 columns, `C-u 4 PgDn`.

Comment: Follow-mode provides commands for this, I think I named them follow-next-page and follow-previous-page. (I'm not at my computer right now and it was 25 years ago I wrote the command, so I might remember wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

thankyou Lindydancer for the clue, and the editors for helping shape my text

I had a look at the available `M-x follow-` completions
and
checked their descriptions with `C-h f`
before running the ones that seemed about right.

The ones below achieve what I wanted :)

```
M-x follow-scroll-up
```

Scroll text in a Follow mode window chain up.

```
M-x follow-scroll-down
```

Scroll text in a Follow mode window chain down.